# How to fetch the set value first-name using Protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I need to store the value of first-name using protractor script. The first-name gets set when the user logs in and it is the name of the logged in user. If it is achievable using `by.addLocator()`.

Below is my tag, it is getting set in app-root.

```
app-root path="/" first-name="abc" last-name="def" is-admin="false"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `app-root` is the tag here you can try something like this

```
root_element = element(by.tagName('app-root'));
root_element.getAttribute('first-name').then((name)=>{
       var first_name  = name;
       //add an expectation to equal something that you're expecting.
       expect(name).to.equal(logged_in_user_name) 
});
```